# Postgres RULE to NOTIFY with NEW column name is not now working

Tags: postgresql, notify

I wanted to get notified when there is any INSERT into my table say EMPLOYEE table. So for that I have used RULE feature of postgres. That will NOTIFY me if there is any INSERT happens to the EMPLOYEE table.

Here is the way I have create my EMPLOYEE table -

```
create table public.employee ( id serial, fname varchar not null, lname varchar, constraint employee_pkey primary key (fname) );
```

Here is the way I want to create my RULE. But it is failing with error -

```
testdb=# create or replace rule employee_tbl_rule as on insert to public.employee do (notify employee_tbl_event, NEW.fname);
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NEW"
LINE 1: ...to public.employee do (notify employee_tbl_event, NEW.fname)...
^
testdb=#

**Any suggestion - Why "NEW" cannot be used with NOTIFY ?**

**I do not want to use -**

- Trigger - Wanted to avoid PLSQL way.
- select pg_notify() for rule - As this will through extra out put post row insertion.

Comment: The payload can't be dynamic: The “payload” string to be communicated along with the notification. This must be specified as a simple string literal.

Comment: Thank you @FrankHeikens for your reply. I was guessing the same. That mean I am left with two options - Either use Triggers or use select pg_notify("channel_name", NEW.column_name_one || ' | ' || NEW.column_name_two).

Comment: Yes, correct. I would pick the trigger

Comment: I was trying to avoid PL/SQL code. So was planning to use RULE instead of TRIGGERS.

Comment: Why? PL/pgSQL is just so powerful, I love it! And the manual even warns for RULE's, there is even a warning: Caution
In many cases, tasks that could be performed by rules on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE are better done with triggers.

Comment: @FrankHeikens you are right just a plain RULE is not that useful. Trigger will be better to use as there we can have some validations as well.